# What's the best way to install a system-wide certificate from a website?

Tags: authentication, vpn

I want to use the Cisco Easy VPN to connect to the OpSource cloud machines. When I open the app, it directly shows a certificate error message, I suspect that the certificate is not trusted from their domain because I tried it on a Windows machine and I had to add an exception for it.

I am using Fedora 15 and I want to make the certificate to this domain accepted system-wide, The only way to get the certificate will be by accessing it through the browser and exporting the certificate from Firefox for example.

How could I install this certificate, and is there a better way to obtain it other than exporting it from the browser?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the better way is to obtain the CA certificate for whoever generated the certificate, then install that into your SSL system.  Here are instructions for how to install that in OpenSSL:

http://gagravarr.org/writing/openssl-certs/others.shtml#ca-openssl

Then it will be able to validate the certificate properly.